# How do I select unique from one of two fields? (that doesn't equal a certain value?)

Tags: mysql, sql, select, unique

Essentially what I want to do is select the most recent message between one user anyone they either received or sent a message to. This means that the unique user id I need could be either in the m_to or m_from. So how can I filter a search to select a unique id from one of two fields, where the field is not the main user's id? Am I making sense here?

```
SELECT * FROM messages
WHERE m_to = '$user_id' OR m_from = '$user_id'
ORDER BY date
```

So just to (try to) be clear, I need to make a query that will select the most recent message either received or sent from the main user for every user they've received or sent a message to. This way there aren't duplicated users in the list. However since this could either be in the to or from field, I have no clue how to do this. Can anyone lend me a hand here?

EDIT: Okay, apparently I wasn't clear. the $user_id variable is the user id of the logged in user. Meaning I need unique messages from either the m_from or m_to field which is NOT $user_id

EDIT:

If we're running this query...

SELECT
  the_user,
  the_other_party,
  MAX(date) AS max_date
FROM (
  SELECT
    CASE m_to   WHEN 'IxjXgC' THEN m_to ELSE m_from END AS the_user,
    CASE m_from WHEN 'IxjXgC' THEN m_to ELSE m_from END AS the_other_party,
    date
  FROM messages
  WHERE m_to   = 'IxjXgC'
     OR m_from = 'IxjXgC'
) m
and let's say we have these categories in the database...

```
m_to    m_from     date
IxjXgC  ShJiMr   2012-01-22 01:20:37
ShJiMr  IxjXgC   2012-01-22 02:22:37
LhJiM1  IxjXgC   2012-01-22 03:23:37
```

and I run the query above, then the result becomes...

```
the_other_party     date
ShJiMr              2012-01-22 03:23:37
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will not accuse you of being lazy (I'm no better than you in that regard, I'm afraid), but I'll agree with Andreas Rohde in that you should exert yourself to listing the necessary columns explicitly as often as possible. Doing so may really help you to see solutions that otherwise would be less obvious, if at all.

Take your present problem, for instance. You need a sort of GROUP BY query that would disregard a user's status as a sender/receiver. Why, you could simply *substitute* sender for receiver and vice versa, in once case, and leave them unchanged in the other. Consider this then:

```
SELECT
  CASE m_to   WHEN '$user_id' THEN m_to ELSE m_from END AS the_user,
  CASE m_from WHEN '$user_id' THEN m_to ELSE m_from END AS the_other_party,
  date
FROM messages
WHERE m_to   = '$user_id'
   OR m_from = '$user_id'
```

The result set will contain rows where the user in question will always be returned as `the_user`, and the other party, well, as `the_other_party`.

Of course, since we made sure that `'$user'` is returned in the same column, the first CASE can be got rid of:

```
SELECT
  '$user_id' AS the_user,
  CASE m_from WHEN '$user_id' THEN m_to ELSE m_from END AS the_other_party,
  date
FROM messages
WHERE m_to   = '$user_id'
   OR m_from = '$user_id'
```

That is, if you need that column at all.

Anyway, you can now aggregate the result set of the above query, e.g. like this:

```
SELECT
  the_user,
  the_other_party,
  MAX(date) AS max_date
FROM (
  SELECT
    CASE m_to   WHEN '$user_id' THEN m_to ELSE m_from END AS the_user,
    CASE m_from WHEN '$user_id' THEN m_to ELSE m_from END AS the_other_party,
    date
  FROM messages
  WHERE m_to   = '$user_id'
     OR m_from = '$user_id'
) m
GROUP BY
  the_user,
  the_other_party
```

You can also join the last query as a subselect back to `messages` on `(messages.m_to = agg.the_user OR messages.m_from = agg.the_user) AND messages.date = agg.max_date` to get the rest of the columns.

Comment: This has been a big help in me getting my head around this, but after hours of trying to create a similar solution, I still can't get it working... When I try implementing your technique specifically, I keep getting an error saying there's something wrong with my synax, even when I try directly copying and pasting.

Comment: @itdoell: I had run out of commas and I noticed that only this minute. Sorry! I've updated my answer now.

Comment: Thank you, this has been a huge help. However I am still running into a major issue with this. The query is only returning one result (from all the users you've messaged or received a message from) So while it is grouping the to/from together, it's not doing it for every person. Additionally, it is just returning the max_date with the_other_party, regardless of whether that other party sent that message. I'll make an update to the main post explaining in a moment.

Comment: Oops, sorry I didn't mean to edit your post =P I meant to edit my own.

Comment: @itdoell: Even though I meant to show you how to group data in this case, I somehow managed to omit the very GROUP BY clause. Oh well... Sorry again, should be fine now.

Answer (score 2):

If you want this for only one user **$user_id** your query is nearly complete .. just reverse order to newest first (DESC) and limit output to 1

```
SELECT * FROM messages 
WHERE m_to = '$user_id' OR m_from = '$user_id' 
ORDER BY date DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

answer to the edit:

```
SELECT * FROM messages 
WHERE not (m_to = '$user_id' OR m_from = '$user_id') 
ORDER BY date DESC
```

messages where the user is either the receiver nor the sender

---

List of person how stand in contact with $user_id

```
SELECT DISTINCT IF(m_to=$user_id, m_from, m_to)
FROM messages 
WHERE m_to = '$user_id' OR m_from = '$user_id'
ORDER BY date DESC
```

Comment: No, the $user_id is the session for that user that is logged in.

Comment: But the user NEEDS to be either the sender or the receiver. I just need to get the person they are either sending the message to or receiving the messages from, without their being any duplicates of the person they're talking to.

Comment: Okay now I know what you want ... 3. try ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think you want this:

Given a user A, return the latest message M for all users B user A ever had a conversation with.

The following statement would give you the maximum date for each user B the user A exchanged messages with:

```
select
    m2.this_user,
    m2.other_user,
    max(m2.date) max_message_date
from    
(
    select
        m.*,
        IF(m.m_to = '$user_id', m.m_to, m.m_from) as this_user,
        IF(m.m_to = '$user_id', m.m_from, m.m_to) as other_user,
    from
        messages m
    where
        m.m_to = '$user_id'
        or m.m_from = '$user_id'
) m2
group by
    m2.this_user,
    m2.other_user
;
```

Using this information, you can get the complete message details by joining back to `messages`:

```
select
    m3.*
from
    messages m3
    inner join
    (
         select
         m2.this_user,
         m2.other_user,
         max(m2.date) max_message_date
     from    
     (
         select
             m.*,
             IF(m.m_to = '$user_id', m.m_to, m.m_from) as this_user,
             IF(m.m_to = '$user_id', m.m_from, m.m_to) as other_user,
         from
             messages m
         where
             m.m_to = '$user_id'
             or m.m_from = '$user_id'
     ) m2
     group by
         m2.this_user,
         m2.other_user
    ) d
        on  ((m3.m_to = d.this_user and m3.m_from = d.other_user) or
             (m3.m_to = d.other_user and m3.m_from = d.this_user))
        and m3.date = d.max_message_date
;
```

I am pretty sure that there is a less verbose way, but this should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM messages WHERE m_to = '$user_id' 
union
SELECT * FROM messages WHERE m_from = '$user_id' 
ORDER BY date desc Limit 1
```

I think this will solve your problem. By the way don't use `*` for this kind of queries. It's recommended to use the column-names you want the values from.